# Web Application into Moodle

Tags: moodle

I developed a web application (in PHP) for students to use it so we can evaluate them. This application generates a final note.

I wonder if Moodle has some activity / module that allows me to embed my web application so that the students can use Moodle.

I've seen that have a Moodle 2.0 activity / module called "External tool", and it might be what I'm looking ... but I have some questions about this activity.

- "External Tool" shows me a Moodle external Web application, is there
  any way to communicate with the external application, for
  example, for example, to save the mark obtained in the Web application the user logged into Moodle?
- Moodle documentation on "External Tool" is not extensive
  (http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Using_External_tool). You can show me
  some reference where I can see how to adapt my Web application to
  communicate with Moodle through "External tool"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external tool uses the [IMS LTI (Learning Tools Interoperability interoperability standard](http://www.imsglobal.org/toolsinteroperability2.cfm) to communicate with external tools. It does allow grade information to be exchanged. I believe the LTI standard uses some form of oauth under the hood, though the [specification](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/blti/bltiv1p0/ltiBLTIimgv1p0.html) isn't so friendly.

You might find it quicker to make a simple Moodle activity modules if you are used to php and have the ability to install plugins on the Moodle server.

Comment: Do you know some tutorial or example about how to connect an external tool with Moodle using LTI?

Answer (score 0):

Moodle wants you to use its Gradebook - it actually works quite well. Is there a particular reason you want use your own program over the inbuilt one?

Comment: What do you mean with "Moodle wants you to use its Gradebook"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that rather than using a homegrown grading app, you can use the Gradebook that's in Moodle, but I think I misread your question. Dan's suggestion re LTI or making your own PHP plugin would be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My english is very poor ;)